# What is $\chi_{A_i}$

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

What is $\chi_{A_i}$ in eq(1)? I couldn't find the definition of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function or indicator function of the set $A$. This is the function defined by $\chi(a) = 1 \;\text{when} \;a \in A$ and $\chi(a) = 0$ otherwise. A bit more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a set, usually $χ_A$ refers to the characteristic function of $A$, i.e.
$$
χ_A: X → \{0,1\}, χ_A(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x∈A\\0&\textrm{else}\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is the characteristic function on $A_i$. It is defined as $1$ on $A_i$, $0$ elsewhere.